# Best way to handle MultipartFile on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2 and `spring-boot-starter-web` I have a controller where I receive file and string id

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/attachment/{applicationId}", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity attachment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable String applicationId) {
```

This project just persist the file into mongo data, so the service just create ths document and persist it

I would like to add some validation to MultipartFile File, like size file, extension file and virus scan.

I was thinking on add a `HandlerInterceptor` class to intercept the request, make the validation and then continue if I get success or just decline the transaction.
or I can adding Service Class to do the same

but what option is the most elegant or the best way to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer this way.

In the very first line of your controller, call the validation method like `validateUploadedFile(file)` and perform the needed validation.

The validation would look something like this.

```
private void validateUploadedFile(MultipartFile file) {
    validateExtension(file);
    validateFileSize(file);
}

private void validateExtension(MultipartFile file) {
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
    if (!"png".equals(extension) && !"jpeg".equals(extension) && !"jpg".equals(extension)) {
        throw new InvalidFileExtensionException("Only jpg/jpeg and png files are accepted");
    }
}

private void validateFileSize(MultipartFile file){
    if (file.getSize() >= MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE_ALLOWED) {
        throw new BusinessException("File size cannot be greater than 5 Mb");
    }
}
```

PS: The **`FilenameUtils`** class is from `org.apache.commons.io` I am only accepting files with extension jpg,jpeg and png.

Comment: do you suggest a service class to validate?

Comment: Yes create one validator class and put your logic there.